# Python SafeConfigParser variable substitution, explanation of variable syntax?

Tags: python, environment-variables, configparser

I just started using Python's ConfigFile.SafeConfigParser class to parse a config file that contains variable definitions and references. It works nicely, but I can't find an explanation for the weird syntax for a variable reference:

```
BASEPATH = C:\Users\me\x
SOME_FILE_PATH = %(BASEPATH)s\a
# Yields C:\Users\me\x\a
```

What's the 's' for? Are there other characters that make the variable behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax comes from Python's [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) syntax, which is based on [C printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) syntax.

In short, `%s` means "substitute with a **s**tring", `%(abc)s` means "substitute with a string named `abc`":

For example:

```
>>> print "Hello %s!" % 'world'
Hello world!
>>> print "Hello %(name)s!" % dict(name='world')
Hello world!
```